# Delphi TClientDataSet Locate problems

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tclientdataset, locate

I'm using `Delphi7`, `MS Vista` and `Devart's dbExpress` drivers (version 4.70). I drop a `TSQLConnection`, a `TSQLTable` (`tabA`), a `TDataSetProvider`, a `TClientDataSet`(`cdsA`), a `DataSource` and a `DBGrid`.

I made all the settings via graphical design tool. Everything works fine, as I open `cdsA`, I can see all the data in the Grid. Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fields, values: string;
begin
  cdsA.Close;
  cdsA.Open;
  fields := 'fielda;fieldb';
  values := Edit1.Text+';'+Edit2.Text;
  cdsA.SetKey;
  cdsA.Locate(fields, values, [loCaseInsensitive]);
end;
```

`fieldA` and `fieldB` exists in table and are defined in `cdsA.Fields` too. When I execute this code the `Locate` instruction generate exception `EVariantInvalidArgError ... Invalid argument`. I'm wondering what's wrong. TIA.

Francesco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is wrong. :)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fields, values: string;
begin
  // Closing the CDS and opening it every time is foolish. Just
  // open it if it's not already open.
  if not cdsA.Active then
    cdsA.Open;

  // List of column names. Since column (field) names are always
  // strings, can just use semicolon-separated values
  fields := 'fielda;fieldb'; 

  // Values for columns. Since these could be any type, you can't
  // simply use semicolon-separated strings. You have to pass an
  // array of Variants. The easiest way is to just create it and
  // populate it, and let reference counting release it when it's
  // out of scope
  values := VarArrayOf([Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text]);  

  // No call to SetKey here. SetKey is used with FindKey, not Locate
  cdsA.Locate(fields, values, [loCaseInsensitive]);
end;
```